# simple if and else statement is not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num1[5];
    int num2[5];
    int equal=0;
    int i;
    cout<<"enter the integers values in num1"<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        cin>>num1[i];
    }
        cout<<"enter the integers values in num2"<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
       cin>>num2[i];
    }
     cout<<"the values in first arrays are ";
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"\t"<<num1[i];
    }
    cout<<"the values in second arrays are ";
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"\t"<<num2[i];
    }
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            if(num1[i]=!num2[i]){
                 cout<<"both arrays are not equal"<<endl;
             }
            else{
                cout<<"both are equal"<<endl;
             }

         }  

    system("pause");
}
```

i have made a simple program in which i have declared arrays num1 and num2 i am actually comparing both arrays but if statement is not working however else statement is working fine whenever i compare both arrays by putting different values it should have to print cout<<"both arrays are not equal"< statement but it is not printing it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change :

```
if(num1[i]=!num2[i]){
          ^^
```

to

```
if(num1[i]!=num2[i]){
          ^^
```

`=!` is assignment of negated `num2[i]` and I doubt you want to do it.

Also you should get warning of suspicious code here:

```
prog.cc:27:32: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
             if(num1[i]=!num2[i]){
```

Comment: @Raheel, always compile with warnings enabled, or better, -perror (treat warnings as errors) to catch such tyops

Comment: @RaheelAlmis consider marking this answer as "accepted". It's a nice way of saying "thanks" to marcinj, and also shows people that you don't need another answer (ie. it "closes" this question).

Comment: @Raheel Almis: here you go: "Accepting Answers: How does it work?" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/328524

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for not equal to is != rather than =!. Check for that and I guess the program will run fine.

!= is the not equal to operator where as =! operates as inversion and then assignment.
For example if the expression is a=!b then it is interpreted as a = (!b) and hence it assigns rather than comparing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer corrects OP problem. But to have a complete answer, I encourage you to explain difference between `!=` and `=!`. For future, I encourage you always to explain answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, It's better to finish "FOR" when there are different numbers and you know the arrays will be different. So you're saving processing time (Also, I think, the code is cleaner and simpler than before).

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(num1[i]!=num2[i]){
        cout<<"both arrays are not equal"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

cout<<"both are equal"<<endl;
```